# text-manipulation: how to exclude specific lines with sed

Tags: replace, sed, text-manipulation

currelty i replace all the `<` in all the content with the following `sed` command

```
sed -e 's/\&lt;/</g''
```

but now i have to exclude the lines that contains `<title>` 
to be exact i have to exclude the text between `<title>` and `</title>`

eg. the following line matches my command but this line should be excluded ...

```
 <title>BEWEGUNGSBOX der ÖDG ab sofort &lt; erhältlich </title>
```

how can i solve it with sed?
i'm using sed in cygwin

Answer (score 0):

To make substitution only in the document body you can use regex ranges in sed:

```
sed -e '/<body/,/<\/body/ s/\&lt;/</g' input.htm
```

Comment: It could work for the OP but your assumption is not exact. It would be with the `<head>` tag, but not with `<title>`.

Comment: thx, but i have to do the substitution in all the document, except the title line, therefore the body would not be enough. So I was thinking if there is a negation for the following search of the title..
sed -e '/<title/,/<\/tile/ s/\&lt;/</g' input.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of using `sed` to handle HTML data. But said that, try this:

```
sed -ne '/<title>.*<\/title>/ { p; b }; /<title>/,/<\/title>/ { p; b }; s/\&lt;/</g; p' infile
```

It looks for a `<title>...</title` with both tags in the same line and prints it without change. Otherwise, look for those tags in different lines using a range. From the point where one of the previous condition don't succeed, begin to substitute `&lt;`.